# Why doesn't QTableView row count update?

Tags: qt, qtableview

I created a `QAbstractTableModel` called `PresetTableModel`, and connected it to a `QTableView`.  I implemented the `rowCount`, `columnCount`, and data functions. Everything works if I have `rowCount` return a fixed number, but as soon as I get it to return a variable value, the list view doesn't show any rows. The debug statement in the code below shows the size value starting at 0, but changing to 9 once the list gets populated.

```
int PresetTableModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex & /*parent*/) const
{
    qDebug() << preset_list.count();
    return preset_list.size();
}
```

Is there something else I need to do to force it to update the number of rows?

Comment: Why not call the same function in qDebug and return statements?

Comment: Thanks Karlson, tried that but no difference.

Comment: Try This:  Set the length of your list to a variable and try returning it.  See if this makes any difference.  I am not sure why it would but doesn't hurt to try.

Answer (score 7):

When modifying the underlying data, you must use the model's notification mechanism to notify the views. E.g, when appending data:

```
beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), preset_list.size(), preset_list.size()+1); //notify that two rows will be appended (rows size() and size() + 1)
preset_list.append(something);
preset_list.append(somethingelse);
endInsertRows(); //notify views that you're done with modifying the underlying data
```

Accordingly, you have to call beginRemoveRows() and endRemoveRows() when removing rows, and emit dataChanged() when existing entries are updated.

On a side note, your rowCount() method should read

```
if (!parent.isValid())
    return preset_list.size(); //top-level: return list size
else
    return 0; //list item: no further children (flat list)
```

to limit the depth. Otherwise each item in the list has again preset_list.size() entries.

Answer (score 3):

i use:

```
 void refresh() {
    emit dataChanged(index(0, 0),
                     index(rowCount(), columnCount()));  // update whole view
    emit layoutChanged();
  }
```

Comment: This does work, but you should use:

emit dataChanged(index(0, 0), index(rowCount() - 1, columnCount() - 1));

instead because the values are indexes, not counts.